# problem settinfg column span (setSpan) in QTableWidget with Python

Tags: python, qt, qtablewidget

I have my header information in HeaderCol objects (below) that hold the text, the actual row the text is to appear on (it is one of the first two rows) the start column, and the span (number of columns)

I have the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QApplication, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout


class TenantEvent:

TENANT_EVENTS = []

def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text
    TenantEvent.TENANT_EVENTS.append(self.text)


class HeaderCol:
    MAX_COL = 0
    HEADERS = [[]]

    def __init__(self, text, row, col, span=1, header_row=0):
        if row == 0:
            HeaderCol.MAX_COL += col
        self.text = text
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.span = span

        if len(HeaderCol.HEADERS) <= header_row:
            HeaderCol.HEADERS.append([])

        HeaderCol.HEADERS[header_row].append(self)


class TransactionsTable(QTableWidget):
    HEADER_TOP_ROW = 0
    HEADER_SECOND_ROW = 1

    col = 0
    row = HEADER_TOP_ROW
    ENTRY_COL = HeaderCol('Entry', row, col, 2)
    col += ENTRY_COL.span
    DUE_COL = HeaderCol('Due', row, col, 4)
    col += DUE_COL.span
    PAID_COL = HeaderCol('Paid', row, col, 7)
    col += PAID_COL.span
    MANAGEMENT_COL = HeaderCol('Management', row, col, 2)
    col += MANAGEMENT_COL.span

    col = 0
    row = HEADER_SECOND_ROW

    DATE_COL = HeaderCol('Date', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += DATE_COL.span
    EVENT_COL = HeaderCol('Event', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += EVENT_COL.span
    FEES_AND_CHARGES_COL = HeaderCol('Fees & Charges', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += FEES_AND_CHARGES_COL.span
    RENT_COL = HeaderCol('Rent', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += RENT_COL.span
    TAX_DUE_COL = HeaderCol('Tax', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += TAX_DUE_COL.span
    TOTAL_DUE_COL = HeaderCol('Total Due', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += TOTAL_DUE_COL.span
    PAID_COL = HeaderCol('Paid', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += PAID_COL.span
    PAYMENT_METHOD_COL = HeaderCol('Payment Method', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += PAYMENT_METHOD_COL.span
    CHECK_NUMBER_COL = HeaderCol('Check Number', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += CHECK_NUMBER_COL.span
    DATE_BANKED_COL = HeaderCol('Date Banked', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += DATE_BANKED_COL.span
    RENT_COL = HeaderCol('Rent', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += RENT_COL.span
    TAX_PAID_COL = HeaderCol('Tax', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += TAX_PAID_COL.span
    TOTAL_PAID_COL = HeaderCol('Total Paid', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += TOTAL_PAID_COL.span
    TENANT_STATUS_COL = HeaderCol('Tenant Status', row, col, 1, 1)
    col += TENANT_STATUS_COL.span
    EXPENSE_COL = HeaderCol('Expense', row, col)
    col += EXPENSE_COL.span
    MANAGEMENT_FEE_COL = HeaderCol('Management Fee', row, col)
    HeaderCol.MAX_COL = col + MANAGEMENT_FEE_COL.span
    NET_COL = HeaderCol('Net', row, col)
    col += NET_COL.span
    NOTES_COL = HeaderCol('Notes', row, col)
    col += NOTES_COL.span

    FEE_DUE_EVENT = TenantEvent('Fee Due')
    MANAGEMENT_EXPENSE_EVENT = TenantEvent('Management Expense')
    RENT_DUE_EVENT = TenantEvent('Rent Due')
    LATE_FEE_EVENT = TenantEvent('Late Fee')
    RENT_PAID_EVENT = TenantEvent('Rent Paid')
    FEE_PAID_EVENT = TenantEvent('Fee Paid')
    BOUNCED_RENT_CHECK_EVENT = TenantEvent('Bounced Rent Check')
    BOUNCED_CHECK_FEE_EVENT = TenantEvent('Bounced Check Fee Due')
    REPAIRS_AND_MAINTENANCE_EVENT = TenantEvent('Repairs & Maintenance')

def __init__(self, data, *args):
    QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
    self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)

    self.data = data
    # self.set_data()
    self.setRowCount(20)
    self.setColumnCount(HeaderCol.MAX_COL+30)
    self.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.resizeRowsToContents()

def add_headers(self):
    print(f'{"text":>15}\trow\tcol\tr_s\tc_s')
    for header_row in range(2):
        for header in HeaderCol.HEADERS[header_row]:
            row = header_row
            col = header.col
            row_span = 1
            col_span = header.span
            print(f'{header.text:>15}\t{row}\t{col}\t{row_span}\t{col_span}')
            self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
            new_item = QTableWidgetItem(header.text)
            self.setItem(header_row, header.col, new_item)

class TransactionsDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        super().__init__()
        top_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.table = TransactionsTable(data, *args)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        top_layout.addLayout(layout)
        self.setLayout(top_layout)
        self.resize(2400, 600)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = {'col1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
            'col2': ['1', '2', '1', '3'],
            'col3': ['1', '1', '2', '1']}

    dialog = TransactionsDialog(data, 4, 3)
    dialog.show()
    dialog.exec()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The print output is this (which looks correct to me):

```
           text row col r_s c_s
          Entry 0   0   1   2
            Due 0   2   1   4
           Paid 0   6   1   7
     Management 0   13  1   2
        Expense 0   14  1   1
 Management Fee 0   15  1   1
            Net 0   15  1   1
          Notes 0   16  1   1
           Date 1   0   1   1
          Event 1   1   1   1
 Fees & Charges 1   2   1   1
           Rent 1   3   1   1
            Tax 1   4   1   1
      Total Due 1   5   1   1
           Paid 1   6   1   1
 Payment Method 1   7   1   1
   Check Number 1   8   1   1
    Date Banked 1   9   1   1
           Rent 1   10  1   1
            Tax 1   11  1   1
     Total Paid 1   12  1   1
  Tenant Status 1   13  1   1
```

The problem is that the cells are not laid out correctly and don't get the correct text:

The first column and row are correct (Entry 0   0   1   2)
The first two cells on the first row are spanned together.
The problem is that the next entry (Due 0   2   1   4) on the first row merges all of the rest of the cells on the first row and I assume because there are no more cells on the first row, the rest is distrubuted down the table.  I have tried stopping after the second entry, but the problem of taking up all the rest of the cells on first row is still there.

[image]

I just tried the following code:

```
def add_headers(self):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    row_span = 1
    col_span = 3
    self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
    row = 0
    col = 4
    row_span = 1
    col_span = 3
    self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
```

The first two cells were merged in row 1 but the next cells remained as normal.  Arrggh!

OK, I boiled my problem into this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!       !               !                       !                               !
!       !               !                       !                               !
!       !               !                       !                               !
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !
! col=0 ! col=1 ! col=2 ! col=3 ! col=4 ! col=5 ! col=6 ! col=7 ! col=8 ! col=9 !
!       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !
-       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !
-       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !       !
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    row = 0
    col = 0
    row_span = 1
    col_span = 1
    self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
    new_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"setSpan({row}, {col}, {row_span}, {col_span})")
    self.setItem(row, col, new_item)
    col = 1
    col_span = 2
    self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
    new_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"setSpan({row}, {col}, {row_span}, {col_span})")
    self.setItem(row, col, new_item)
    col = 3
    col_span = 3
    self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
    new_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"setSpan({row}, {col}, {row_span}, {col_span})")
    self.setItem(row, col, new_item)
    col = 6
    col_span = 4
    self.setSpan(row, col, row_span, col_span)
    new_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"setSpan({row}, {col}, {row_span}, {col_span})")
    self.setItem(row, col, new_item)
    return
```

This does not work at all:
[image]

Comment: Just tried some pretty simple code (see above) it didn't work :-(

Comment: I boiled my problem down two a few lines of code and a diagram for simplicity (see the end of the post).  I have been trying all kinds of different solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
In the constructor, I found that I was resizing the table after I set the headers.